# MCA and FAMD bad scores for UCI census dataset

Tags: dimensionality-reduction

Attempting dimensionality reduction on the [Census-Income (KDD) Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census-Income+(KDD)).

The dataset is a mixed dataset with continuous and categorical features.

PCA works fine for continuous variables, reduced down to 2 PCA variables.

`[0.84686919 0.14737952]`

But having difficulties with categorical variables and cont/cat together.

There are 2 options that are not working out.

1. multiple correspondence analysis (MCA - for categorical variables)

```
[0.022592513816454877, 0.022074753604733162, 0.01779832534650477, 0.01644525961669972, 0.013596646212654651]
```

2. factor analysis of mixed data (FAMD - for continuous and categorical variables).

Will add these later but they are also very low - not picking up variance in data

Any ideas/tips ?

Comment: does this help https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90347/calculating-correlation-for-categorical-variables/90361#90361 ?

Comment: Thanks will take a look. In the meantime I'm looking at autoencoders as an alternative.